# django - restrict model access

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mezzanine

I'm using Django, Django Rest Framework and Mezzanine.

I've set the following in settings.py for DRF -

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),

'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
```

If not logged in I can't access the pages.  This is good so far.

I then did the following to my models.py -

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ["Date"]
    permissions = ( 
        ( "view_tablename", "Can view tablename" ),
    )
```

Again, everything is working.  I can now see the option when I go into my admin panel for Users and Groups on my app.

I then add the DjangoModelPermissions to my settings.py

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),

'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',
),
```

And my views.py still continues to pull the page even though I don't have the user set to have view access to that model.

```
class File_List(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = tablename
    serializer_class = tablename_compositesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases for
        the user as determined by the username portion of the URL.
        """
        filename = self.request.GET.get('filename')
        model = get_model('database', filename)
        filedate = self.request.GET.get('filedate')
        queryset = model.objects.using('testdb').filter(Date__contains=filedate)
        return queryset
```

What am I doing wrong in being able to restrict a model from a user?

Comment: Is your model named tablename? If you have a serializer_class, doesn't it already specify the model? Anyway, I think you have to take care of permissions manually when you're getting a custom queryset using get_queryset(). You could always try commenting out the get_queryset method and do something like queryset = ModelName.objects.all() and see if the permissions work as desired then.

Comment: Also, it seem like you're specifying the model at the top and than getting a different model in get_queryset based on the request URL. What's going on there?